# ReactJS - Lazy load images - chrome native - Unknown prop `loading`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, lazy-loading

has anyone got around the `Unknown prop "loading" on <img> tag. Remove this prop from the element.` issue that happens when trying to apply `loading="loading"` in ReactJS to apply the new chrome feature?

It seems that something that is so simple seems to be rather difficult.

Is there a way to bypass the validation??

Thanks!

Comment: I dont see any error from React. Where are you getting this error in? What version of React are you using, are you using typescript?

Comment: @Rikin we are on 15.6.2. I'm literally applying this to <img src="" alt="" loading="loaded"/> and get the above error on chrome console

Comment: I guess that could be reason version of react usage, which may not support it and `loading="loaded"` is also not one of the valid value: https://whatpr.org/html/3752/edc1e95...2ebd8ae/urls-and-fetching.html#lazy-loading-attributes You may want to upgrade React version and see if the error still occurs. Is it IDE error or you get error on the browser or console?